If someone pings me in a comment; can I see which specific comment I was pinged in from the Global Inbox?
I have posted multiple comments under someone else's question or answer. When someone pings me in a comment (using @myname to notify me), my question is:

Can I know if the person is pinging my most recent comment, or can they ping a specific comment of mine? Or, am I only notified without being able to see which comment they are replying to?

I know I can use the Global Inbox to view the recent replies to things I have written. How do I view the recent replies to things I have written?
But my reputation is too low, so I am unable to comment.


I want to know if a ping in a comment can point to a specific comment, or if it can only notify a specific user.

When I have posted many comments in the past, how can I know which specific comment they are replying to?



I can't ask the question properly because I don't have enough reputation.

You should have copied the content of your question over to this one instead of leaving an essentially empty question body like that...

You only need 5 reputation to post here on Meta, @FulaiCui ; it doesn't take long to get.

@AbdulAzizBarkat They should not have. Neither question should exist. Posting to meta for no rep users is only to discuss their actual questions on main. That’s also why there is the notice comment in the meta question source.


I want to know if a ping in a comment can point to a specific comment, or if it can only notify a specific user.

No, comment replies don't point to any specific comment and only serve as a way to notify another user who has participated in a particular comment thread.

When I have posted many comments in the past, how can I know which specific comment they are replying to?

There's no sure way to know which comment a reply is for, you can only depend on the context (content of the reply and of previous comments) to guess what it is replying to.
If the comment thread is so big that you're getting confused about this you should consider whether you are using comments for the correct purpose, as per the help center:

You should submit a comment if you want to:

Request clarification from the author;
Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the
question has been updated).



For instance, user_A: XXX; user_B: XXX; user_A: XXX; user_D: @user_A, XXX. That is, to understand the last comment, do I have to look back at user_A's previous comments?

@FulaiCui probably? As I said comment replies aren't (and can't be) linked to any of the previous comments you can only guess from the context.

Some users will (helpfully) quote (part of) the comment they are replying to when it would be ambiguous, @FulaiCui, but that relies on the author of the comment doing do. There's no built-in feature or requirement to do that.

@ThomA, I get it. The community only provides the ability to ping the previous user to come back to the thread if wishes.

"As I said comment replies aren't (and can't be) linked to any of the previous comments you can only guess from the context" just to clarify - the system does try to link them but only in order to know when to send a notification. For short comment threads, it sort of works (this is using the threaded comments userscript which follows the system rules for notifications). But it's by no means perfect. You indeed cannot know what comment another replies to. In some cases it's not even a "reply".

I would say that the moment you want to add a third comment under the same content, you have to really question what's going on and that's when that help center page on commenting is a nice reality check. It is so easy to go over the line (and create unnecessary workload for other people in the process) because as human beings it is hard to let a challenge go unmet and a person wrong on the internet to go unchecked.
